# GWT DevMode won't run due to Unknown argument: -module

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I'm trying to run a GWT project in DevMode under the Eclipse SDK and I get the below error message, despite that my Debug/Run configuration clearly states the module name in the GWT tab and the -module param is provided in Program arguments:

```
Unknown argument: -module
Google Web Toolkit 2.5.1
DevMode [-noserver] [-port port-number | "auto"] [-whitelist whitelist-string] [-blacklist blacklist-string] [-logdir directory] [-logLevel level] [-gen dir] [-bindAddress host-name-or-address] [-codeServerPort port-number | "auto"] [-server servletContainerLauncher[:args]] [-startupUrl url] [-war dir] [-deploy dir] [-extra dir] [-workDir dir] module[s] 
where
[...]
module[s]        Specifies the name(s) of the module(s) to host
```

Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: WHat parameter we require to pass?

Answer (score 1):

Read the usage message more closely: `module[s]` does not mean `-module`. Look how, for instance you can read `-logLevel level` but not `-module modules`. The module name(s) aren't preceded by a `-module` switch, they're just listed as-is as the last arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much, Thomas, you fixed the issue straight away!